# What does Control Word do for 8255?

Tags: microprocessor

If `RDnot, WRnot, A0, A1` pins can decide which ports to choose and whether to read or write data, then what is the purpose of a control word in [8255](http://aturing.umcs.maine.edu/%7Emeadow/courses/cos335/Intel8255A.pdf)? What is it used for?

Comment: Please link the data sheet and state which page the control word is mentioned.

Comment: Very old device ... and very "versatile".

Comment: This question is answered very well by the IC datasheet and existing 8255 application data on the Internet. (I've not the opportunity to post links but I read lots on 8255 back in its day (and recently) and did hw/sw for them, so I know it's there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Justme

Here are the full mystery addresses ... of 8255.
Just write to "control register" and then read or write the port A, B, C in the 1 of 3 chosen "mode" and "specials" configurations.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Control port is used to configure the ports into different modes, such as generic input, generic output, or strobed inputs or outputs, etc.

Comment: So, either (a) I can directly operate it via the above mentioned pins or (b) I can use the control word to do the data transfer?

Comment: No, you need to first configure the chip into the mode you want to use it in, before you can use the chip in the mode you want to use it.

Comment: But if control word is how you configure the chip (select mode, determine which port is I/O, etc.), then what is the use for the A0 and A1 pins? I am sorry, but I am new to all this.

Comment: They are address pins determine which of the four addresses (registers) you want to write or read. One of the addresses is used for accessing the config register, three addresses are for the three ports.